# Dynamic date change based on getdate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

One of our dependent tables are fed only on third day of month, I need to write a query first two days it should check for previous month data from 3rd on wards current month data.

Tried with `CASE`expression which did not work

```
select case when datepart(day, getdate()) <= 2 
            then (select * from T1 where date in (201904,201903))
            else (select * from T1 where date in (201905,201904))
       end
```

I know my approach is wrong, need help to achieve what I required.

Comment: Are you storing dates as strings? What's the datatype of Date column? It looks like the datatype is `INT`.

Comment: Why does your sample code have two months but your explanation only mentions one month?

Comment: It is a month end data, instead of feeding month end date, IT is loading the date as YYYMM format

Comment: Hi Gordon, It is grammatical mistake, I would have mentioned months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this to "flag", if it's within the first 3 days or not. 
it is formatted to look a dates as a INT.

```
DECLARE @Currentday AS INT

SET @Currentday = cast(replace(cast(GETDATE() AS DATE), '-', '') AS INT)

IF @Currentday BETWEEN cast(replace(cast(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) AS DATE), '-', '') AS INT)
        AND cast(replace(cast(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 2) AS DATE), '-', '') AS INT)
    -- if within first 3 days
    SELECT 1 --insert your own statement
ELSE
    -- if not within first 3 days
    SELECT 2 --insert your own statement
```

Comment: Hi Mmolle, Thank you for your help, I will give it a try

Comment: Hi Mmolle, Is there any way to insert the result of the above query in a temp table

Comment: Glad it did the trick, would appreciate with you would upvote it ;) 
You can just convert your SELECT statement to insert into a temp table: 
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM TABLE1
Just remember to delete the temp table before you run the code again

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a guess, but something like this?

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM {Your Table} YT
WHERE YourDateColumn >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())),0)
  AND YourDateColumn < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()))+1,0);
```

Comment: I don't think the datatype of `Date` column is `DATE`, it's a string or an number (INT). Still it's a guess as you already said

Comment: Hadn't noticed that they were 6 digit ints. Perhaps you're right @Sami, but then maybe reason the `CASE` didn't work didn't work is because `201905` was converted to the datetime `2452-10-18 00:00:00.000` :/